# Angular 2 Tooling for Visual Studio 2013 vs Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, angular

We have a project written in ASP.NET MVC, WCF, and Angular 1.  This year we are moving from Angular 1 to Angular 2.  We are currently running Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.  Does Visual Studio 2015 offer any other capabilities for Angular 2 or TypeScript that is not already in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Did you mean "not already in Visual Studio 2013? (Not 2015)? If so, check this out: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html especially this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Deborah.  I really enjoyed your PluralSite course.